# Auto complete in asp.net using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

Here I'm trying to use jquery auto complete in asp.net, I'm trying to retrieve the data from sql data source and use that for auto fetch. while I running the code auto complete have not worked.

my code

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "Inventory.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtPartno').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

textbox field

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPartno" CssClass="Textboxbase" class="autosuggest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and my c# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
[WebMethod]

public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MYPC-GN\\KASPLDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT PART_NO from Inventory where UserName LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(dr["UserName"].ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: no errors, but have not retrieve the data as expected.

Comment: Does your `GetAutoCompleteData` gets hit?

Comment: it seems no., any way to check that(debug)

Comment: Can you please make sure that the function you described in C# is hitting by placing a break point?

Comment: put a break point on the line List<string> result = new List<string>(); and then debug to see if it is actually retreiving any records. since the alert is not prompted it can only mean that the autocomplete call is a success

Comment: I've inserted break point but it haven't retrieved any data, it seems like function haven't hit.

Comment: Try to return `JsonResult` and include `List` in `JsonResult`

Answer (score 0):

One problem which I can see is your javascript call is little wrong. You cannot get the value of textbox which is created by asp itself with `document.getElementById('txtPartNo')`. To get this value, you will have to get it's client id which you can get using-
`txtPartNo.ClientID` so finally this will become-

```
data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('<%= txtPartno.ClientID %>').value + "'}",
```

If you don't try this way then you will not get the actual value of that textbox and `undefined` will be sent to the C# method which will not return anything.

Comment: Tried dude, still it hasn't retrieve data,,,

Comment: Can you add an attribute that is `ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)` ?

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if the JavaScript function it's getting called.
If it's getting called then you should check if the url is correct.
You can check in developer tools/ firebug etc. to see what request are you sending.

Answer (score 0):

I did as follows:

**ajaxCallSetting.js**

```js
var ajaxCallSetting = function (element, message, req) {
    var baseInfo = {        
        baseUrl: "http://localhost:10266/"
    };
    var buildUrl= function() {
        return baseInfo.baseUrl + message;
    };

    var callApi = function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: buildUrl(),
            data: JSON.stringify(req),
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function(data) {
            response(data.d);
        });
    };
    
    return {
        init: function() {
            $(element).autocomplete({
                source: callApi
            });
        } 
    };
};
```

**The head tag:**

```html
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ajaxCallSetting.js"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var req = {
                 username: $('#txtPartno').val()
            };
            apiSettings('#txtPartno', "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData", req).init();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

As far as possible,
Keeping separate Html code with the code in JavaScript is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your TextBox is being hooked up properly. Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPartno" CssClass="Textboxbase autosuggest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And try this in your JavaScript:

```
$(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Inventory.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```